# Searching Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, search, attachments

I am trying to create a search template to search attachments uploaded to a custom post type called folders. This is what I have so far:

```
if ( $post->post_type == 'attachment' 
    && $post->post_parent == '343' 
    && $post->post_mime_type == 'application/pdf' ) 
{ 
    ?><a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $post->ID, true ); ?>" target="_blank">
}
```

At the moment this searches for attachments uploaded to the post 343 what I need it to do is search any posts that belong to the folders custom post type.

Comment: Have you found a solution that you can share with us?